# Change UIView constraint height brings its subview's constraints warning

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have a UIView `parentView` with subviews. All the constraints are set correct.

When I want to make this `parentView` hidden by `heightConstraint.constant = 0` and show it by `heightConstraint.constant = 200`. I will get warnings like:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

I can get it because the `subviews` constraints not satisfied with the new height.

So is this possible by changing the `heightConstraint` and meanwhile satisfied subview constrains?
(I can achieve it by `parentView.isHidden`, just don't want to use this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Because of your subview has `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom`  with some `constant`  to the `parentView`

let's say 10 all sides  `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` now
 when you set your `height` 0   subview has not enough space to satisfy 10 value to the top and bottom  of the sides. so it is showing error

Try to give priority to low to `top` and `bottom` or if that not work give your all subview height constant with > 0 low priority

Or Use Stackview (Vertical) for subview and use `spacing` instead of top and bottom

Hope it is clear to you that why this thing happening

Comment: @WilliamHu Glad that solution worked for you !! Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same warning and I did the same what @prashanttukadiya suggested.

Decreased the value of height constraint in storyboard by 1, by default it is 1000 :

[image]

and the warnings were removed.